How to configure a single prompt for multiple queries in SAP Rich Client Web Intelligence?
I´m new in SAP Rich Client BO.
I have 2 queries and both use 2 different universes, but with common variables ('cnpj' and 'data_inicio').
Each variable was merged between the 2 universes. When I try to set a single prompt for both queries, for 'cnpj' it works but for 'data_inicio' doesn't. Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.


The properties of the prompts need to be identical for them to be grouped and prompted for together. Given that the time ("00:00:00") is shown for your prompts from Query 1 and not Query 2 it would seem that your objects in Query 1 have a data type of DateTime and in Query 2 they are just Date.
You could solve this in Custom or Free-hand SQL in Query 1 by converting your DateTime column to a Date and adjusting the data type your prompt is expecting. So you would go from something like this...
WHERE YourTable.YourDate = @Prompt('Enter Date','DT',,Mono,Free,Not_Persistent,,User:0)

to this...
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, YourTable.YourDate) = @Prompt('Enter Date','D',,Mono,Free,Not_Persistent,,User:0)

A better option would be to create another object in your universe that does the the data type conversion from DateTime to Date.
Keep in mind that if your column that is a DateTime data type, you are losing data for that last day of your range where the time values are anything greater than "00:00:00" (Midnight). Convert to a Date data type and then using that in your query criteria solves this problem.

Thanks a lot! Based on you answer, I found a object in Query 2 that has data type of DateTime. Solved!

If your filter is YourDateTimeColumn <= "05/04/2024" you will miss data at the end of your range with values like "05/04/2024 10:30:18" since when no time is specified midnight ("00:00:00") is assumed.
